# /etc/network/interfaces - generic network configuration

Tags: linux, network-interface

I have two single board computers from orange pi, each with two onboard Network adapters. One of them  usually referred to as eth0, whereas the other one changes from board to board. It take different names like enxc0742bffdf83 and enxc0742bffdf6e. An Armbian image is what I'm using to power the board. I configured the two network adapters on one of them so that they would not automatically obtain an IP address from DCHP. I did that by by modifying the /etc/network/interfaces file as shown below.

```
auto  eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

auto  enxc0742bffdf6e
iface enxc0742bffdf6e inet manual
```

I want to be able to copy the image that I configured manually into another SD card and run it directly without having to manually alter the /etc/network/interfaces again. Is there an option to use a generic alias name, such as adapter-1 and adapter-2, that works for all boards? If not, is there a way to create a general script that will automatically update the /etc/network/interfaces file at system startup with the correct name of each board's adapters?

Comment: Is _not_ using /etc/network/interfaces an option? Debian already includes an alternative network configuration system with much better support for generic configs.

Comment: Yes it is an option. I just used  /etc/network/interfaces because it is what I am familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

The network interface names starting with `enx...` include the MAC address of the NIC in question. It is probably assigned because of the file `/etc/systemd/network/81-usbnet.link`.

See `man systemd.net-naming-scheme` and `man systemd.link` for more details.

Depending on the properties of your second NIC, you might or might not be able to write a generic `/etc/systemd/network/*.link` file that would match the second NIC on any of your boards and assign it the name you want. If you can do this, create a `*.link` file like this and name it so that it sorts before `81-usbnet.link` in basic ASCII alphanumerical sort order:

```
[Match]
<some condition that matches your second NIC>

[Link]
NamePolicy=
Name=<your desired name for the second NIC>
```

If your system uses an initramfs, you might need to recreate it so the `*.link` file will get included in it, and will take effect even if the NIC drivers are loaded while the system is still running in initramfs.

---

Or if you are sure that the kernel-assigned names like `eth0` are stable on your systems, you could add the kernel boot parameter `net.ifnames=0` and you would get two network interfaces simply as `eth0` and `eth1`. Just make sure that your network interface driver modules will always be loaded in the same order. You might want to add something like this into a `/etc/modprobe.d/*.conf` file:

```
install <second_NIC_driver> /sbin/modprobe <first_NIC_driver> && /sbin/modprobe -i <second_NIC_driver>
```

This will ensure that even if the kernel would load the driver for the second NIC first for some reason, the module load process will always load the driver for the first NIC before it, so that the first NIC will always catch the name `eth0`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of /etc/network/interfaces, consider using the `systemd-networkd` service (comes with the system).

Enable the service and configure your network through `/etc/systemd/network/*.network` files (see `man systemd.network`), which can be configured to match interfaces on various criteria – for example, interface name wildcard, or driver name:

```
[Match]
Name=enx*

[Network]
...
```

```
[Match]
Driver=r8188eu

[Network]
Address=...
```

(The list of `*.network` files is read in ASCII alphabetical order and each interface is configured from the *first* matching file only, which is shown in `networkctl status`. For example, you could have specific static configuration in "20-eth0.network" that matches an exact name, followed by generic DHCP configuration in "50-other.network" that matches all Ethernet devices.